# Nodejs / Gulp doesn't copy all files to the 'dist' folder

Tags: node.js, express, gulp

Gulp should copy all sub-folders and files to the dist. But it copies only half of them, some folders will be ignored even if I change their names etc. (no special characters, same subfolder structure as the once that got copied correctly ...) - nothing worked. I just can't see any pattern in this.

There is no error message while running gulp. Nothing that would help me find the error.

This is my gulpfile.babel.js :

```
import path from 'path'
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const babel = require('gulp-babel');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
import del from 'del';
import nodemon from 'gulp-nodemon';

const paths = {
  js: ['./**/*.js', '!dist/**', '!node_modules/**', '!coverage/**', '!./*.test.js'],
  statics: ['./package.json', './.gitignore', './.env', './templates/**/**/*'],
  resources: ['./resources/**/*'],
  public: ['./public/**/*'],
  templates: ['./templates/**/**/**/*'],
  tests: './server/tests/*.js',
}


gulp.task('clean', function (done) {
  del.sync(['dist/**', 'dist/.*', 'coverage/**', '!dist', '!coverage'])
  done()

});

gulp.task('copy', function (done) {
  gulp.src(paths.statics).pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
  gulp.src(paths.resources).pipe(gulp.dest('dist/resources'))
  gulp.src(paths.public).pipe(gulp.dest('dist/public'))
  gulp.src(paths.templates).pipe(gulp.dest('dist/templates'))
  done()
})
gulp.task('build', function (done) {
  gulp.src([...paths.js, '!gulpfile.babel.js'], { base: '.' })
    .pipe(babel(
      {
        presets: ['@babel/env']
      }
    ))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
  done() 
})
gulp.task('start', function (done) {
  nodemon({
    script: path.join('dist', 'index.js'),
    delay: 1000,
    ext: 'js',
    tasks: ['clean', 'copy', 'build'],
    ignore: ['node_modules/**/*.js', 'dist/**/*.js'],
  })
  done()
})
gulp.task('serve', gulp.series('copy', 'build', 'start'))
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('serve'))
```

a lot of folders, for example The folder `dashboard` in `routes`, does not copy to the dist file.

This is my structure:

```
- backend
- > server
- > server > routes
- ...
- > server > routes > dashboard
- > server > routes > dashboard > *.js 
- ...
- gulpfile.babel.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `copy` task is creating multiple streams with multiple calls to `gulp.src`. The correct way to combine them is to use `merge-stream`:

```js
const mergeStream =   require('merge-stream');

gulp.task('copy', function () {
  return mergeStream(
    gulp.src(paths.statics).pipe(gulp.dest('dist')),
    gulp.src(paths.resources).pipe(gulp.dest('dist/resources')),
    gulp.src(paths.public).pipe(gulp.dest('dist/public')),
    gulp.src(paths.templates).pipe(gulp.dest('dist/templates'))
  );
})
```

Alternatively, since you're simply copying your folder structure in the `dist` folder, you could also do this:

```js
gulp.task('copy', function () {
  return gulp.src([...paths.statics, 
                   ...paths.resources,
                   ...paths.public,
                   ...paths.templates], 
                   {base: '.'})
          .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
})
```